# How do you properly override the User Agent Stylesheet in a React Project?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

From what I gather there is a precedence to inheriting CSS values, and elements inherit alot of their values from the User Agent Style Sheet in an attempt to set some standard. Im in chrome and the h5 element is inheriting the display value and the only way I am able to override it is by using inline CSS * "shivers".

[image]

This is the CSS inline that I'm applying :

[image]

Ive created a separate CSS style sheet which Im importing in App.js to make changes to other elements in this same component.

[image]

This style sheet is working on i.icon for example, but no matter what way I try to select the h5 and even if i add !important, I still cant get the h5 element to be display : inline.

[image]

Can someone shed some light on this, my current solution is inline CSS as mentioned but I dont think this is good practice.

Comment: user agent rules are "per element" so even if you just include an `h5 { display: inline }` in your own CSS master file, it'll "win" and set the display value to `inline`. Of course, using `h5` means you're saying that the content inside of it is a fifth-level heading. Note the "-ing ending: it's _not_ a "header" it really is quite specifically [a (text) section heading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) =) For real tables, use `th`, and for fake tables, use a `span`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight Mike! Super informative :)